# Line Graph not showing value in apex:chart

Tags: apex, visualforce, charts

I am creating one line bar graph using `apex:chart` . In this graph values are not getting displayed.

Here is the following code for it
**VF  Page**

```
  <apex:chart height="400" width="900" data="{!GraphData}">
                    <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" fields="data1" title="Amount" grid="true"/>
                    <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="name" title="Month of the Year" />
                    <apex:lineSeries axis="left"  xField="name" yField="data1" markerType="circle" markerSize="10" markerFill="#F08F35"/>
                    </apex:chart>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class NewOfferPageExtension {
 public List<Data> GraphData{get;set;}
   public NewOfferPageExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
       GraphData = new List<Data>();
        GraphData .add(new Data('Jan', 30, 90, 55));
        GraphData .add(new Data('Feb', 44, 15, 65));
        GraphData .add(new Data('Mar', 25, 32, 75));
        GraphData .add(new Data('Apr', 74, 28, 85));
        GraphData .add(new Data('May', 65, 51, 95));
        GraphData .add(new Data('Jun', 33, 45, 99));
        GraphData .add(new Data('Jul', 92, 82, 30));
        GraphData .add(new Data('Aug', 87, 73, 45));
        GraphData .add(new Data('Sep', 34, 65, 55));
        GraphData .add(new Data('Oct', 78, 66, 56));
        GraphData .add(new Data('Nov', 80, 67, 53));
        GraphData .add(new Data('Dec', 17, 70, 70));


    }

     public class Data {
        public String name { get; set; }
        public Integer data1 { get; set; }
        public Integer data2 { get; set; }
        public Integer data3 { get; set; }
        public Data(String name, Integer data1, Integer data2, Integer data3) {
            this.name = name;
            this.data1 = data1;
            this.data2 = data2;
            this.data3 = data3;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: The values are not getting displayed]

Comment: I just ran the code you posted in an empty page and the data1 line rendered fine and I could add the other lines too. So the above code is good - perhaps you changed something when posting here? Or there is something else in the page affecting the chart? Otherwise a mystery to me what the problem is.

Comment: @KeithC No I didn't change anything while posting code.I have included static resource in the page for CSS

Comment: Suggest you start with only the above code (which does display a line for me and confirm it does for you) and then add back in other page content to find what is causing the problem.

Comment: ok let me try and i will let you know

Comment: @KeithC: i got the problem : It is CSS issue

Comment: Cool. You can answer your own question and accept that answer (after I think a day or so) so the question is then listed as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the CSS issues it is not happening so we try to solve the problem of CSS and then try it.

After removing the bootstrap CSS from page it works fine.

Comment: Shantanu.. Nice work. Can you pls add few lines or any suggestion how you fixed this issue using CSS.

Comment: Actually this error is because of  Bootstrap CSS

Comment: @ShantanuMahajan what you have changed in bootstrap CSS that resolved this issue ?

Comment: @sfdcweb: I have commented it the whole Bootstrap CSS